# Save specific match into a variable

Tags: regex, bash

I have a file that contains the following example:

```
*
ABCD Z12,
$ (67,EAGL165XQ.58,AD=0.0001,SF=7.0,TC=EAGL165XQ.58,LY={70},DT={0},BX=0.0,BY=0.0,UX=240.0,UY=8000.0)
ROWS 41860/111496
*
```

All I need is to get the first occurrence of `EAGL165XQ.58` into a variable. How can I do that with regex?

Comment: `EAGL165XQ.58` is a fixed string, not a pattern, so what does this have to do with regex? Please [edit] to clarify. I'm asking cause the trivial answer is `x=EAGL165XQ.58`.

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/Fnf7zk/1) might help you to get the first instance of your input, which is bounded from the left with <kbd>,</kbd>:

```
,([A-Z0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})
```

You can simply call it using `$1`.

[image]

Comment: The practical use with GNU grep: `grep -Po ',\K([A-Z0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})' file`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `sed`, but you must use the `0,addr2` address range (see [sed(1) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html)) to set `sed` to be at the end of its range on the first match, e.g.

```
$ sed -n '0,/.*EAGL/s/^[^,]*[,]\(EAGL[^,]*\),.*$/\1/p' < file
EAGL165XQ.58
```

**Explanation**

- using the `0,addr2` pattern before the normal substitution `s/find/replace`, where
- `find` looks for the first comma `[,]` followed by `EAGL`, using
- a capture group `\(...\)` to store the matching `EAGL...` up to the following  comma, and where
- the backreference `\1` is used as `replace` to replace the entire line with the contents captured between `\(...\)`

To capture the result in a variable, you can use *command substitution*, e.g.

```
$ myvar=$(sed -n '0,/.*EAGL/s/^[^,]*[,]\(EAGL[^,]*\),.*$/\1/p' < file)
$ echo $myvar
EAGL165XQ.58
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu bash

```
while IFS=',=' read -r s
do
 [[ $s =~ EAGL165XQ\.58 ]] &&{ var=${BASH_REMATCH} ;break; }
done <file
```

tried on gnu sed

```
var=$(sed  -En 's/[^,=]*.(EAGL165XQ.58).*/\1/p' file)


echo $var
EAGL165XQ.58
```